# Array from the last element to the first

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
array([[-1.2825],
       [-0.9202],
       [-0.0809],
       [-0.1469],
       [-0.3981],
       [-0.1422],
       [-0.0132]])
```

and I would like the first element to be the last, second element to be the second from the end etc. How can I do this?

```
array([[-0.0132],
       [-0.1422],
       [-0.3981],
       [-0.1469], 
       [-0.0809],
       [-0.9202],
       [-1.2825]])
```

Comment: By "array" you mean a NumPy array?

Comment: Have you tried anything? What was the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the flip function from numpy:

```
import numpy as np
yourarray = np.array([[-0.0132],
       [-0.1422],
       [-0.3981],
       [-0.1469], 
       [-0.0809],
       [-0.9202],
       [-1.2825]])  
reversed_array = np.flip(yourarray)
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you maybe know how can I change now this array into one dimensional array of the form:

`np.array([-0.0132,
       -0.1422,
       -0.3981,
       -0.1469, 
       -0.0809,
       -0.9202,
       -1.2825]) ` i.e without brackets?

Comment: Yes, you can use the flatten method: `reversed_array.flatten()`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming its list or numpy:

```
a= a[::-1]
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    if i + i + 1 > len(array):
        break
    array[i], array[-i - 1] = array[-i - 1], array[i]
```

Comment: This is a really bad solution. Take a look at the other solutions to see how to revert a list or an array.